# Trying to get the keyup to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I have this code that when a user inserts a score it will check to see if the user entered 0.50 or .50 for example and validate it so the user can enter either or.

But my problem is when the user enters a new score the they have to press enter or click outside the box for the save button to enable.

So I was wanting to add the `.keyup` or `.keypress` events so it will enable whenever the user starts entering data, but I run into an error.

If I change it to the `.keyup` it doesn't do the validation. Can someone take a look at this code and let me know what I'm not seeing? How do I get this to work? Thanks.

```
aResponse.append(
        jQuery('<div />', {'class':'responseScore'}).append(
            jQuery('<span />', {'text':'Score for above response: '}),
            jQuery('<input />', {'type':'text', 'maxlength':10, 'placeholder':'Score', 'value':(response.score%1==0?response.score.toFixed(1):response.score), 'tabindex':(i+1)})
              .bind('change', function(){
                var that=this;
                var score = this.value;
                if (score.length > 0 && isNaN(parseFloat(score))){
                    $(this).addClass('invalidNumber');
                    alert("That is not a valid number.");
                    $(this).val('');
                    setTimeout(function(){that.focus();},5);
                    return;
                }
                else
                    if ($(this).hasClass('invalidNumber')) $(this).removeClass('invalidNumber');
                var responseID = $(this).parents('.groupResponse').attr('qrid');
                var response = responses.filter(function(item, index) {return item.id == responseID && responseID != undefined})[0];
                if (score.length == 0)
                    response.attr('score', '');
                else
                    response.attr('score', parseFloat(score));

                $("#saveButton").button('option','disabled',false);
            }),
            jQuery('<span />', {'text':' / '+(response.question.weight%1==0?response.question.weight.toFixed(1):response.question.weight)})
        )
    );
```

Comment: I'm not seeing your `keyup` function.

Comment: If you change `.bind('change',` to `.bind('keyup',` you get an error?  What does the error say?

Comment: Well I took it out I was adding the .keyup where the .bind is to see if that would work but I need that there for the validation to work.

Comment: when I do .bind('keyup', it works but when I enter .50 it doesn't do the validation and will give the error. I want the user to be able to enter .05 or 0.50

Comment: Oh and the error that pops up is the one in the code stating that it is an invalid number.

Comment: Have you thought about using .on instead of binding all your events as you add them? It will simplify this code a lot. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: .keyup will fire every time. so, if someone types 0, it'll fire - so 0.50 means it'll fire 4 times. I would try to add a count so that it will not fire until user enters a period.

Comment: I've tried the .on() and seem to run into same issue. Also the counter would work if user had to enter a period but the user can enter whole numbers as well so would the counter still be beneficial?

Comment: I think so. if statement should look for a 0 or a "." else it should work for a whole number.

Comment: or you can try using blur instead of change.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still not able to get the validation and .keyup to work at the same time. I'll keep trying.

Comment: in my opinion, I think you should keep the validation to work on change or blur.

Comment: I want to keep that, but I would like it to be able to enable the save button to when they enter data. Some people seem to have an issue with having to click outside the box in order to have the save button enabled.